# Provisioning profile failed: Profile doesn't include the com.apple.developer.device-information.user-assigned-device-name entitlement

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios16

I request and got permission for capability for "User Assigned Device Name".

[image]

Here my MyApp.entitlements content:

[image]

When I install App on my Device via Xcode, I can access real Device name.

But when I try to upload App, I get following error:

[image]

Someone face same issue?

Bests

Comment: I am having a similiar issue. Received an email saying the provision had been granted, added the key to the .plist file. Tried to build and it fails with a provision failure. I'm guessing I have added the key incorrectly? Or need to do an additional step with my provisioning?

Comment: have u found any solution?

Comment: You must apply for the User-Assigned Device Name entitlement:
https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/user-assigned-device-name/

You will need to request it separately for Development (TestFlight) and Production (App Store upload).